# Parent Pom get version of Child Pom/dependency

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, multi-module, parent-pom

I have a project like the following

mainProject - Multi Module Project structure:

```
pom.xml
newfolder/pom.xml
```

otherProject:

```
otherProject.pom.xml with mainProject.pom.xml as its parent pom and newFolder/pom.xml as a dependency.
```

see below:

mainProject pom.xml:

```
<groupId>test.test</groupId>
<artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>newFolder</module>
</modules>
<dependency>
    <groupId>test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>newFolder</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

newfolder/pom.xml:

```
<groupId>test.test</groupId>
<artifactId>newFolder</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainProject/artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

otherProject:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT/version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>newFolder</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The problem is when I try to build otherProject it cannot find the version of newfolder because it is not pulling in the version of the project that I built it is still looking for newfolder 1.0-SNAPSHOT

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the behavior I was hoping for by adding ${project.parent.version} to the parent pom dependency.  example:

```
<groupId>test.test</groupId>
<artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>newFolder</module>
</modules>
<dependency>
    <groupId>test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>newFolder</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```